# How to match all characters that are not a-zA-Z and "b4g" (matching numbers except when b4g is encountered)?

Tags: php, regex

Trying to understand the negative lookaheads or positive. Basically I want to match everything that isn't in the capture group [a-zA-Z] and the literal string "b4g". So I would be left with just a-z and the b4g literal if it was in the string.

Given: $100b4gb$2000

It would match $100$200

I would do a regex replace all matches, so they would be replaced with `''`.
Something like

```
preg_replace('/(?!.*b4g)[^a-zA-Z]+/', '', $subject);
```

I've tried this and can't get it to work

Matches everything but strips 4 from "b4g"

```
[^a-zA-Z]+
```

Can't get this lookahead to work either

```
(?!.*b4g)[^a-zA-Z]+
```

Comment: `preg_replace('~b4g|[a-zA-Z]~', '', $text)`? Like in https://regex101.com/r/NNGJI1/1?

Comment: The description is a bit inverted. You want to strip `a-zA-Z]` and `b4g`, right? Leaving `$100$200` or do you just want `$100$200` removed?

Comment: Hi thanks for response. Remove all except for a-zA-Z and b4g. I'm using a replace function to replace the matches with `''` essentially stripping them out

@WiktorStribiżew the opposite of that, of course I could take the result of the match I guess, but replace anything not matching that criteria

Comment: So, `preg_replace('~(?:b4g|[a-zA-Z])(*SKIP)(*F)|.~', '', $text)`? Or, `'~b4g(*SKIP)(*F)|[^a-zA-Z]~'`? See [this YT video of mine about SKIP-FAIL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvZ7knJVYW0).

Comment: I tried it in regex101, it just matches first `$` and stops? From what I understand it needs a lookahead right? But you gotta "store" the capture somehow to prevent the 4 from being stripped with all other numbers?

https://regex101.com/r/mBj1Sj/1

Comment: @GarrickCrouch You forgot the `g` flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
preg_replace('~b4g(*SKIP)(*F)|[^a-zA-Z]~', '', $text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MYq5pA/1). *Details*:

- `b4g(*SKIP)(*F)` - matches a `b4g` substring and omits it from the match, and the next search starts from the failure position
- `|` - or
- `[^a-zA-Z]` - any char other than an ASCII letter.

Comment: Nice. That's sick dude. Works perfect. You can wrap the "known" keywords containing numbers or whatever and have an excluded list. Regex is wild